# relation on the set corresponding to matrix M

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

I have the following matrix:

$$M = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

> (a) Write the relation on the set {a, b, c} corresponding to M

What exactly do they mean in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They mean that you call rows of your matrix $a, b, c$ and likewise columns, and then two elements are related if the element at the intersection of row of the first and column of the second has a $1.$ For example, in your matrix, $a\sim a,$ since the top left entry is $1.$